# jquery boot box confirm contains script tag word

Tags: jquery

If `bootbox` confirm plugin contains `<script>` tag, it will shows js error in console. But if I change to `<br>`, it can display correctly. How can I show confirm message if message contains `<script>` word?

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/y3thct54/57/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the characters "<" and ">" to HTML entities. THis code here works because I convert those characters to their entities:

http://jsfiddle.net/j1vxyz97/1/

The function for conversion is this part:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

And I call it with this snippet:

```
htmlEntities('Are<script> you sure?')
```

Does this solve your problem?